# PHP Search multiple words in query against database table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a user query and a database. My database contains tables. What I am curious to know, is my method for querying the database. What I'm thinking is:

- Separate the query into an array split by a space
- Loop through each word and do a LIKE '%{$word}%' OR
- Above that, just prior to each iteration, do an 'AND'

The problem is, its not working correctly. Its not dicing done to precise emails that match my queries. Here is my code:

```
$i=0;
$userQuery = $_POST['q']; // q = "Jonathan gmail"
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE ";
$parts = explode(' ',$userQuery);
$cnt=count($parts);
foreach($parts as $part){
  $part = mysql_real_escape_string($part);
  if($i!==$cnt-1){
        $sql.="(
                addresses.name LIKE  '%".$part."%' OR
                addresses.localpart LIKE  '%".$part."%' OR
                addresses.domain LIKE  '%".$part."%'
            ) AND
        ";
    } else {
        $sql.="(
                addresses.name LIKE  '%".$part."%' OR
                addresses.localpart LIKE  '%".$part."%' OR
                addresses.domain LIKE  '%".$part."%'
            )
        ";
    }
    $i++;               
}

}
```

My question is whats wrong with this logic? It seems accurate.

Comment: And where is the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And could you please provide the `$userQuery` that does not work with your code?

Comment: Done. Added question and query

Answer (score 0):

First of all: This will break on a single word.
Second: This is everything else but safe from an SQL attack.

Now - how I'd do it

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\s,]+/',$userQuery);
$sql=array();
foreach($parts as $part) {
  $part=mysql_real_escape_string($part); //Or whatever works with your DB access framework
  $sql[]="(addresses.name LIKE '%$part%' OR addresses.localpart LIKE '%$part%' OR addresses.domain LIKE '%$part%')";
}
$sql=implode(' AND ', $sql);
$sql="SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE $sql";
```

Comment: I dont understand how Im prone to SQL attack? Im using mysl_real_escape_string?

Answer (score 0):

hey something like this:

```
foreach($parts as $key => $part){
  $part=mysql_real_escape_string($part);
  $sql .= sprintf("(
                addresses.name LIKE %s OR
                addresses.localpart LIKE  %s OR
                addresses.domain LIKE %s
            )", $part);

  if ($key!=($cnt-1)) {
    $sql .= " AND ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little notice, you're using $i variable before initializing it.  Also maybe it will be a better way to use REGEXP. Something like:

```
// $search_terms = '%Jonathan%|%gmail%'
$sql = "addresses.name REGEXP  $search_terms OR addresses.localpart REGEXP  $search_terms    OR addresses.domain REGEXP  $search_terms";
```

More details on [REGEXP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm)

Comment: Now my question is should I be using OR instead of AND. Im trying to lets say grab Jonathan from addresses.name AND gmail FROM addresses.domain and display the results that have both. However, this could run into an issue in that I want to display OR statements too. For example, i wouldn't want a 0 result set because of an AND against addresses.domain when the search query is Jonathan, as it should produce all the results from addresses.name that have Jonathan